# C++ Class, Object and Memory Management

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am beginner to C++ and I am stuck on this question

Using an appropriate file structure, create a class called “Matrix”. This class should have: (1) a private 2D container of floats of type std::array, (2) a method that will populate all elements of the 2D container with a float passed in as an argument, (3) a method to print out to screen the contents of the container in appropriate 2D format, and (4) getter/setter methods for individual elements of the container. For (4), ensure you test for out of bounds requests. Test using suitable code in your main function.

```
    class Matrix
{
private:
    std::array<std::array<float, 3>, 3> arr = { { { 5, 8, 2 },{ 8, 3, 1 },{ 5, 3, 9 } } };
public: 
    void display(); 

};
int main()
{
    Matrix Matrixclass;
    Matrixclass.display();

    return 0;
}
void Matrix::display()
{
    cout << "Values inside the container: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)             //rows
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)         //columns
        {
            std::cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Am I on the right track? Cheers.

Comment: Does everything work as expected? So you probably are.

Comment: That depends on which track you're on. Obviously, a track that leads to Emerald City would be the right track, but a track that ends by plunging in a bottom-less abyss would be the wrong track. And only you know which track you're on...

Comment: Apparently the code has `using namespace std;` somewhere. That's definitely on the wrong track. There are good reasons for putting the standard library in its own namespace, and blowing away the namespace is not a good idea. Also, don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does; `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @PeteBecker not necessarily. It could just be `using std::cout; using std::endl;`, wich would be fine.

Comment: @besc - care to bet on it? <g>

Answer (score 0):

std::array is for a fixed size array. Unless you just want to implement a 3 by 3 matrix. Using std::vector is probably a better choice if you are planning to have more dimension matrix in the future. Make sure you do size validation.

Another option is using template which would give you flexibility to have other types of matrix.